# How to ask a user for an accurate date in a date format

Tags: swift, date, uipickerview

So I have a program which I need to ask a user for a date and time. But that date has to either be in the future or the the very far past. And I have tried a `UIDatePicker` but have found out that a date picker isn't the best way to tend to this sort of problem because it requires a lot of scrolling, and the it doesn't load past a certain date for some reason. I was thinking of a `UIPickerView` that asks for Year, Month, Day, and Time. But I don't know how to do it because lets say that the month is September there is only 30 days so then how can I stop the user from selecting 31. So if anyone can help me that would be amazing. And if you have any questions or need for code just ask. Oh and by the way I would like it in a date format where I can compare it to other date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the `year` and `month`, you can calculate the array of possible `day` values to be supplied to your picker like so:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let components = DateComponents(year: year, month: month, day: 1)
guard let date = calendar.date(from: components),
    let range = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: date) else { return }
let days = Array(range)
```

---

> I would like it in a date format where I can compare it to other date.

Once you have the `year`, `month`, and `day`, `hour` (converted to 24 hour value, from 0 to 23), you can build the `Date` object like so:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let components = DateComponents(year: year, month: month, day: day, hour: hour, minute: minute)
guard let date = calendar.date(from: components) else { return }
```

That `date` can now be compared to any other `Date` object.

Comment: How would I incorporate time(including am and pm)

Comment: Convert hour to 24 value (where 0 = 12am, 1 = 1am, ..., 11 = 11am, 12 = 12pm, 13 = 1pm, ..., 23 = 11pm) and then supply this 24 hour adjusted value to the `DateComponents` initializer.